# how to print TextEntryDialog value in list box?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I want to know how I can use the value from a text entry dialog
from the `def textentry` function in the `def __init__` function of the
class such as in the `wx.ListBox` where asd is printing on the right
side.

Here is the code :

```
        import wx

        class main_window(wx.Frame):
            def SetOutput(self, output):
                self.output = output
            def OnSelChanged(self, event):
               """
               If an output function is defined, we try to print some
               informative, interesting and thought-provoking stuff to it.
                If it has a __doc__ string, we print it. If it's a function or
                unbound class method, we attempt to find the python source.
                    """
                item =  event.GetItem()
            def textentry(self, event):
                dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Enter URL','URL Parsing')
                dlg.SetValue("Default")
                if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                     self.SetStatusText('You entered: %s\n' % dlg.GetValue())
                     return (dlg.GetValue())
            def opendir(self, event):
                dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_NEW_DIR_BUTTON)
                if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                     self.SetStatusText('You selected: %s\n' % dlg.GetPath())
                dlg.Destroy()
            def OnExit(self,e):
                self.Close(True)
            def __init__(self, parent, title):
                wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500),style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
                status=self.CreateStatusBar()
                splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style=wx.SP_3D)
                splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(1)
                menubar=wx.MenuBar()
                first=wx.Menu()
                second=wx.Menu()
                third=wx.Menu() 
                first.Append(106,"a","a")
                first.Append(104,"Open","Browse")
                first.Append(100,"anything","yup")
                first.Append(105,"Exit","Quit")
                second.Append(101,"s","s") 
                menubar.Append(first,"File")
                menubar.Append(second,"Tool")
                menubar.Append(third,"Contact us")
                self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.textentry, id=106)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=105)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.opendir, id=104)
                self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(splitter,1, style=wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT|wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
                """
               If an output function is defined, we try to print some
               informative, interesting and thought-provoking stuff to it.
                If it has a __doc__ string, we print it. If it's a function or
                unbound class method, we attempt to find the python source.
                    """
                root = self.tree.AddRoot('wd')
                os = self.tree.AppendItem(root, 'sa')
                cl = self.tree.AppendItem(root, 'a')
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelChanged, self.tree)
                cunt=wx.ListBox(splitter, -1, (100,100), (100,100), 'asd', wx.LB_SINGLE)
                cunt.SetSelection(1)
                splitter.SplitVertically(self.tree, cunt,200)
                splitter.SetSashPosition(180, True)
                self.Show(True)
                 """
               If an output function is defined, we try to print some
               informative, interesting and thought-provoking stuff to it.
                If it has a __doc__ string, we print it. If it's a function or
                unbound class method, we attempt to find the python source.
                    """
        class App(wx.App):
            def OnInit(self):
                frame = main_window(None, 'S2A vulnerability Scanner')
                return True


        if __name__ == '__main__':
            app = App(0)
            app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do? Do you want to get the input value from the text entry dialog?

Comment: yes i want to get input through entry box and use it out side the class.

Comment: @user333736 yes, you can have a try with the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert the input value into the list box.

1. use `self.cunt` to replace the `cunt`
2. in `textentry` use `self.cunt.Insert(val, 0)` to insert the input value into list

Try following code:

```
import wx

class main_window(wx.Frame):
    def SetOutput(self, output):
        self.output = output
    def OnSelChanged(self, event):
        """
        If an output function is defined, we try to print some
        informative, interesting and thought-provoking stuff to it.
         If it has a __doc__ string, we print it. If it's a function or
         unbound class method, we attempt to find the python source.
             """
        item =  event.GetItem()
    def textentry(self, event):
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Enter URL','URL Parsing')
        dlg.SetValue("Default")
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            val = dlg.GetValue()
            self.SetStatusText('You entered: %s\n' % val)
            self.cunt.Insert(val, 0)
            return (dlg.GetValue())
    def opendir(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_NEW_DIR_BUTTON)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.SetStatusText('You selected: %s\n' % dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()
    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500),style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style=wx.SP_3D)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(1)
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()
        third=wx.Menu()
        first.Append(106,"a","a")
        first.Append(104,"Open","Browse")
        first.Append(100,"anything","yup")
        first.Append(105,"Exit","Quit")
        second.Append(101,"s","s")
        menubar.Append(first,"File")
        menubar.Append(second,"Tool")
        menubar.Append(third,"Contact us")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.textentry, id=106)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=105)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.opendir, id=104)
        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(splitter,1, style=wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT|wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
        """
       If an output function is defined, we try to print some
       informative, interesting and thought-provoking stuff to it.
        If it has a __doc__ string, we print it. If it's a function or
        unbound class method, we attempt to find the python source.
            """
        root = self.tree.AddRoot('wd')
        os = self.tree.AppendItem(root, 'sa')
        cl = self.tree.AppendItem(root, 'a')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelChanged, self.tree)

        self.cunt=wx.ListBox(splitter, -1, (100,100), (100,100), 'asd', wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.cunt.SetSelection(1)
        splitter.SplitVertically(self.tree, self.cunt,200)
        splitter.SetSashPosition(180, True)
        self.Show(True)
        """
      If an output function is defined, we try to print some
      informative, interesting and thought-provoking stuff to it.
       If it has a __doc__ string, we print it. If it's a function or
       unbound class method, we attempt to find the python source.
           """
class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect)

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = main_window(None, 'S2A vulnerability Scanner')
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: in this code the tree on each selection is showing the same thing how can i assign different functions to different tree selections ? such as on 1st selection it show text entry dialog box and on second it show the opendir fuction.